# Существует ли onPause() без onStop()?

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

В теории жизненного цикла Activity существует переход от onPause() к onResume(), но ни эксперименты с запуском AlertDialog, ни входящий звонок на телефон во время исполнения моего Activity, не дают сработки только onPause() без срабатывания onStop().
В какой реальной ситуации на практике происходит срабатывание только onPause() без срабатывания onStop() и происходит ли вообще?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onPause()` всегда вызывается (если с логикой программы всё нормально). `onStop()` может не вызваться, к примеру, если не хватает памяти. Это даже в [документации](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) сказано:

> Это метод может так и не вызваться, в ситуациях, когда не хватает памяти, чтобы продолжить работу вашего `Activity` после вызова `onPause()`.

Так же метод `finish()` ломает логику и не позволяет вызваться нужным ивентам. Если вы напишите что-то такое:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("MainActivity", "onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e("MainActivity", "onPause");

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("MainActivity", "onStop");

}
```

То сработает только `onDestroy()`, а `onPause()` и `onStop()` нет.

Comment: Это собственный перевод или все таки существует русскоязычная документация?

Comment: @maratsoft перевод. Думаю, есть и русские статьи на этот счёт. Я всё на английском читаю, чтоб достовернее.

Answer (score 1):

Если [посмотреть на блок-схему](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) вызова методов жизненного цикла, то можно заметить, что метод `onPause()` вызывается после ухода активити в фон, а метод `onStop()` при ее исчезновении с экрана.

Соответственно, в штатной работе активити, вызов метода `onPause()` без вызова метода `onStop()` возможен, когда активити ушла в фон, но остается видимой на экране, а затем происходит возврат в эту активити.
На практике это может быть, к примеру, вызов диалога и возврат из диалога в активити.

Про нештатные ситуации уже сказали - при уничтожении активити через GC (например, катастрофическая нехватка памяти) будет вызван только `onPause()` и активити уничтожена.